# RESTlet + JAX-RS Authentication Middleware

Tags: java, api, rest, jax-rs, restlet

I'm making a backend API using RESTlet and JAX-RS on app engine. I'd like to make a method that is called before each request to check whether the user is authenticated (has to make a query to an external API via HTTP) and then continue or stop depending.

How could I do this?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be very simple.

Create a subclass of Authenticator (http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/jse/api/org/restlet/security/Authenticator.html?is-external=true) and implement authenticate() with custom authentication and any other functions that are needed.

For example,

```
public class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

public MyAuthenticator(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected boolean authenticate(Request request, Response response) {
    // do your custom authentication here and return true or false depending on result
}
```